# Add options to multiple Selectize inputs on type

Tags: selectize.js

I'm loading several Selectize select inputs in one page, like this:

```
var selectizeInput = [];
$('.select-photo-id').each(function (i) {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    selectizeInput[i + 1] = $(this).selectize({
        'maxOptions': 100,
        'items': [selectedValue],
        'onType': function (input) {
            $.post("admin/ajax/search_photos_for_postcards",
                {input: input},
                function (data) {
                    $(this).addOption(data);
                    $(this).refreshOptions();
                }, 'json');
        }
    });

});
```

The event `onType` makes a function call that returns a list of new options which I want to make available right away in the Selectize input. Is there any way to call the Selectize instance from there? As you can see from the code, I tried accessing it with `$(this)`, but it fails. I also tried with `$(this).selectize`, but it's the same. Which is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it:

```
   'onType': function (input) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.post("admin/ajax/search_photos_for_postcards",
            {input: input},
            function (data) {
                $this[0].addOption(data);
                $this[0].refreshOptions();
            }, 'json');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `load` event provided by the Selectize.js API as seen in [the demos](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/#demos). Scroll until you find "Remote Source — Github" and then click "Show Code" underneath it.